# Error adding controls to did analysis (R)

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to run a multi-period cross-sectional difference-in-difference analysis in r, using the `did` package. My code looks like the following: (with a reduced dataframe)

```
library(did)

df <- structure(list(a = c(0, 0.333, 0.333, 0, 0.333, 0.667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333, 0, 0, 0.333, 0, 0, 0.333, 0.667, 0.333, 0.333),
                      b = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1),
                      c = c(0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3),
                      d = c(0, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0),
                      e = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                      f = c(0.647, 0.324, 0.265, 0.451, 0.206, 0.333, 0.265, 0.51, 0.373, 0.343, 0.48, 0.363, 0.343, 0.245, 0.304, 0.667, 0.392, 0.461, 0.451, 0.363, 0.363, 0.235, 0.392, 0.382, 0.412),
                      g = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L)),
                 class = "data.frame",
                 row.names = c(NA, -25L))

did_test = att_gt(yname = "a",
                        tname = "b",
                        gname = "c",
                        data = df,
                        idname = "g",
                        xformla = ~e,
                        panel = FALSE
                        )
```

But when run it I receive the following error:

```
Check groups: 9.Error in qr.solve(crossprod(wols.x.post.treat, int.cov)/n) : 
  singular matrix 'a' in solve
```

I receive this error regardless of the synatx used (with `~` and without; using `as.formula`; multiple covariates or 1). I also checked the groups and indeed have variation for each group (period) with the covariates. Why is this singular matrix error arising? Can I do anything to fix this so that the covariates can be included in the did model? I regret that I cannot provide the entire dataset to show with 100% certainty, but are there any possible problems causing the error?

Comment: Side comment - please recheck your data.frame, some columns like `a` have 26 values, others like `f` and `g` have 25.